# Convert arraylist to an array for a spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, spinner

I have an arraylist with 2-6 items. The items gets added through some if/else statements.
I have to convert this arraylist(listFartoy) to an array(arrayFartoy) for it to work in a spinner.

Im using the method below:

```
String[] arrayFartoy = new String[listFartoy.size()];
arrayFartoy = listfartoy.toArray(arrayFartoy);
```

It seems to work fine.

But when I put it inside the spinner it wont work.
The line arrayFartoy[position] gets red.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFartoy = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayFartoy);
        adapterFartoy.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_fartoy.setAdapter(adapterFartoy);

        spinner_fartoy.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                selectedFartoy = arrayFartoy[position];

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```

When I used this spinner/adapter with a normal array it works well and the selected item is stored in "selectedFartoy".

It works with this:

```
String[] arrayFartoy = new String[] { "Tarot T960", "Tarot FY680", "Ecilop",
        "Sexycopter", "Skywalker" };
```

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? What happens when you try it?

Comment: post the code from `String[] arrayFartoy = new String[listFartoy.size()];` to `selectedFartoy = arrayFartoy[position];`

Answer (score 0):

I think u don't want to convert that ArrayList to  String array. Because u can pass arrayList directly to ArrayAdapter. Like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFartoy = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listfartoy);
adapterFartoy.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_fartoy.setAdapter(adapterFartoy);

    spinner_fartoy.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            selectedFartoy = listfartoy.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```